# stack overflow when returning an ES6 proxy through a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-proxy

I'm trying to intercept a method call on a ES6 proxy to be able to do stuff in between with the information I get from the proxy. Now in my case there is quite some stuff going on before creating and returning the proxy from some kind of factory. Because of all this stuff I decided to wrap the prerequisites into a promise-function so that I can chain the proxy creation right onto it and return the resulting proxy through the promise chain. Here's the code to reproduce the problem:

proxy_factory.min.js

```
'use strict';

// require('harmony-reflect');

class ProxyFactory {

  create(options) {

    const self = this;

    const handler = {

      get(target, propertyKey, receiver) {

        if (propertyKey === 'then') {

          return function proxyPromiseWrapper(thenCallback) {
            const innerProxy = self.create(options);
            return thenCallback(innerProxy);
          };
        }

        return function resourceFunctionProxy() {

          const callContext = {
            target: target,
            method: propertyKey,
            args: arguments,
            thisContext: this
          };

          const resourceInstanceMethod = Reflect.get(options.originalObject, callContext.method);
          return resourceInstanceMethod.apply(callContext.thisContext, callContext.arguments);

        };
      }
    };

    return new Proxy(options.originalObject, handler);
  }

}

module.exports = ProxyFactory;
```

test.js

```
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const ProxyFactory = require('./proxy_factory.min.js');

const proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();

function createProxyWithPromise() {

  const TestClass = class {
    doSomething() {
      return Promise.resolve('promise return value');
    }
  };

  const options = {
    originalObject: new TestClass()
  };

  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      return proxyFactory.create(options);
    });
}

function test() {

  createProxyWithPromise()
    .then((proxy) => {

      const result = proxy.doSomething();

      console.log(result); // should output 'promisereturnvalue'
    });
}

test();
```

Before doSomething() is called on the proxy the then()-function is called over and over again, resulting in a stack overflow.
I already asked this question in the node.js github issues and you can find the previous conversation here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8082
Maybe it helps someone helping me ;)

Comment: Well yes, that `proxyPromiseWrapper` will immediately call the callback with another thenable, not wait for a result. I have no idea what you want to do or why promises would need to be treated specially in there.

Comment: Your proxy is weird. It always returns a function for no matter what property.

Comment: You should not make `ProxyFactory` a class. It does not hold any state, so don't create instances of it. Just export the `createProxy(option)` factory function and be done.

Comment: Yeah `proxyPromiseWrapper` was my attempt to deal with the promise "interfering" with my interception. My problem is that I have to return the proxy through a promise chain and as a result of that only get the call for `then` inside the proxy. What I'm trying to achieve is pretend the then isn't called on my proxy so that I can get the actual method calls that take place after I returned my proxy through the promise chain. I made a class out of it because there's going to be more stuff going on when a call gets intercepted.

Comment: I guess all you need to do is `return undefined` for that. Your proxy should no be thenable if it does not wrap a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your proxy always returns a function for accesses on any property, including `then`. That will make promises implementations treat it as a thenable, trying to to resolve it - where your code went horribly wrong. But you should fix the root of the issue:

```
get (target, propertyKey, receiver) {
    if (!(propertyKey in target))
        return undefined;
    else if (typeof target[propertyKey] != "function")
        return …;
    else
        return function resourceFunctionProxy() {
            …
```

Comment: This did the trick, also I didn't know that short syntax for checking if an object got a key. And now I think I understand the problem as well. Thanks for your help! This kept me awake more than one night already ^^

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the blue, but you might be looking for

```
return function proxyPromiseWrapper(thenCallback) {
    return options.originalObject.then(function(result) {
        const resultOptions = Object.assign({}, options, {target: result});
        const innerProxy = self.create(resultOptions);
        return thenCallback(innerProxy);
    });
};
```