# Achieve Do after and before using ES6 Proxy

Tags: ecmascript-6, interceptor, es6-proxy

I've a View and Utility classes and wanted to hook-in the Utility method once View's job is done. So wanted to call the utility method (to add behavior to the view) once View's render call is done.

Using ES6 Proxy API, Is there a way to execute a method before / after executing the `main` method ? (aka method interceptions)

Similar to YUI3 Do API.
http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Do.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Actually I'm trying to build the same thing and as long as you use a synchronous context I already got it working. Have a look at the code examples in the issue I created for my problem: [stack overflow when returning an ES6 proxy through a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951001/stack-overflow-when-returning-an-es6-proxy-through-a-promise)

What you need to do to intercept the call is to use the ES6 proxy to get notified of the `get`-call that takes place to retrieve the function before the method is actually called.

In my example you can see that you get all the information about the call  like what method was called with which parameters and also who called it and on which target it was originally called.